# How to use while loop to ask the program to try again at the end?

Tags: java

I am trying to use the ***while loop*** combine this two separate program into one and I have been trying this for a week now but still couldn't figure out where to put the "Do you want to try again (Y/N)?" loop. Any help or tips will do..

### **First separate  WORKING program:**

It will ask the user to input three integers. A Starting number, an End number that is greater than the Starting number, and a Step number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;
        int first , second , third ;

        System.out.print("First number: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        first = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.print("Second number:: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        second = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.print("Third number: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        third = Integer.parseInt(input);

        while(first <= second)
        {
            first = second + third;
            System.out.println(first);

        }
    }
}
```

### Example output:

### Start: 1

### End: 10

### Step: 2

### 1

### 3

### 5

### 7

### 9

### **Second Separate WORKING Program:**

It will ask the user to try again.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sample {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    char c = 'y';

    while (c == 'y')
       {
            System.out.println("C");
            System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? ");
            c = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);

        }
    }
}
```

### Example Output:

Do you want to try again (Y/N)? n

---

---

And I am trying to get an an output like this:

---

### Start: 1

### End: 10

### Step: 2

### 1

### 3

### 5

### 7

### 9

Do you want to try again (Y/N)? n

---

If I entered 'y' it should get me back from the very start and ask me to input for the Start,End, and Step. And if I entered 'n' it should terminate the program.
... With only using the **while loop** to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply wrap the first program inside the loop of the second. It will be a little clearer if you separate the operation of the first program into a separate method. The result might be something like this:

```
public class TheProgram {
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static void interact() {

        String input;
        int first , second , third ;

        System.out.print("First number: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        first = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.print("Second number:: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        second = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.print("Third number: ");
        input = in.nextLine();
        third = Integer.parseInt(input);

        while(first <= second)
        {
            first = second + third;
            System.out.println(first);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char c = 'y';

        while (c == 'y') {
            interact();
            System.out.print("Do you wish to continue? ");
            c = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have it as two separate programs? You should just do it in one program and use an if loop that has a bool set to true unless they type no, which typing no would cause the program to exit.